# How can you block VS from regenerating code gen files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When VS regenerates the code gen file due to a change in the markup or code behind of a control it has a habit of deleting all the controls from the code gen.

How do I block VS from regenerating the code gen files so that they can only be edited manually?

Comment: If you block the code generation then any changes you make in the screen editors or XAML or UIMap or etc files will have no effect. The content of those files is made useable in a program by generating code for them.

Comment: The controls we use don't work well with screen editors so that's not a problem. We already have to modify the code gen by hand anyway, blocking the program from re-writing them incorrectly will save me time.

Answer (score 0):

You're not expected to edit generated files.
The classes defined by the code generation are usually partial classes which allows you to complete the definition of the class and apply customization in a separate file.